# Why does replacing an image with javascript disable Jquery on my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

My goal was to have a floating green box follow the scroll and stop at a certain point of my choosing. For the most part I have accomplished this although it's not as smooth as I'd like. My main issue now is when I replace the green box with javascript the new javascript no longer follows the page down as you scroll at all. It seems to disable the previously working jquery for some reason.

```
<div id="follow><img><div> <-- Works 
<div id="follow><javascript><div> <-- Does Not Work
```

I've also noticed that even if I leave the green box where it is but place javascript elsewhere in the body it stops this code from working. Any idea why this is and what I can do to fix it?

See my demo here --> http://jsfiddle.net/Kachish/RqELN/18/

```
  .follow { 
    position: absolute;}
​
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(window).load(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollVal = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.follow').css('top',scrollVal+'px');
    if (scrollVal < 250) { 
    $('.follow').css('top','150px');
    }
    if (scrollVal > 547) {
    $('.follow').css('top','375px');    
    }
    });
    });//]]>  
    </script>
```

Comment: Is there some reason you're loading both MooTools and jQuery? And why would you put a `<javascript>` in the first place? What use is there?

Comment: what is your objective with those top two divs?

Comment: The top two divs were just an example of what works and what doesn't. When all is done I would only have the second one with the javascript.

Comment: The javascript is needed because it's sharing dynamic information from a third party so that's why I can't just use an image.

Comment: the only reason why would new JS disable previous one (in this case) would be the JS error in this new one. Pls check if it raises any exception.

Comment: Thanks Whiteeage. I have checked but wasn't able to find any issues. The javascript is already existing elsewhere on my site and works perfectly fine independently. The new javascript itself also works when I add it to this example, it just no longer floats/follows the scroll bar.